# What does SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID returns?

Tags: active-directory, spcontext

Could anybody kindly let know what does SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID returms. Is it the same ID which Active Directory uses to store ID of user.

Thanks

Comment: No, it's the unique ID for the current user in the site collection. Stored in the hidden user list.

Comment: That is why it says ``CurrentWeb`` . ``CurrentUserID``

Comment: Thanks Chris and Danny for point it out. However i need to know a way to know the ID in Active Directory for a user... Kindly let know how it can be get.